# Getting SQL.Database is not a constructor (leaflet-tilelayer-mbtiles-ts || sql.js)

Tags: angular, leaflet, gis, angular-leaflet-directive, sql.js

While importing any mbtiles file, i get this error :
[image]
I had an error before that was about assigning a value to a readonly property named stack, so after searching a bit i figured that i had to update the sql.js library to a newer version, then i got this error.
Here is the function initializing the map :

```
  initMap(){

    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [48.864716, 2.349014],
      zoom: 8
    });

    const mb = L.tileLayer.mbTiles('assets/countries-raster.mbtiles', {
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 6
    }).addTo(this.map);
    mb.on('databaseloaded', (ev:any) => {
      console.info('MBTiles DB loaded', ev);
    });
    mb.on('databaseerror', (ev:any) => {
      console.info('MBTiles DB error', ev);
    });
  }
```

Can you help me encounter this please. Thank you